# Mixing the 2-adics with base-2 represented reals

Tags: discrete-mathematics, p-adic-number-theory

**TLDR:** 2-adic numbers ($\mathbb{Q}_2$) are expressed as ....01101011.001, meaning an infinite amount of digits on the most significant side and a finite number of "decimals". Base-2 represented reals are the opposite: 110001.0010010111010...., a finite number of digits on the most significant side and an infinite amount of "decimals".

What happen if we mix both? i.e. consider: ....11100101101.1000100001...., infinite amount of digits on the most significant side AND infinite amount of "decimals".

Do we get a field? Is there a name for these "numbers"?

**Longer statement**

**2-adic numbers**

2-adic numbers form a field ($\mathbb{Q_2}$), they are uniquely determined by their sequence of digit which is infinite on the most significant side and finite after the decimal.

Doing operations on 2-adic numbers is "simple" as it is exactly like operations on natural numbers but where you never stop propagating carries.

For instance: ....01010101 represents the number "-1/3" because 2x + x = ....11111 = -1.

2-adic numbers are a non countable field but very different from the reals: no total order and, for instance, you can have square roots of negative numbers.

**Base-2 represented reals**

Any real number can be represented in base 2. Representation is not unique as we have: 0.11111.... = 1

The addition on real numbers is different from the one on natural numbers. The algorithm works by considering successive truncation. In base 10 if you want to add $\pi + e$ you will successively consider: 3 + 2 = 5, 3.1 + 2.7 = 5.8, 3.14 + 2.71 = 5.85, 3.141 + 2.718 = 5.859 etc...

**Mixing both**

Although 2-adics and reals have very different properties, the symmetry of their representation is striking: .....1111101.01 VS 10011.00111100...

This begs the question: what happens if we consider "numbers" of the form .....10101.00101011..... ?

What about representation uniqueness? Do we get a field? Or at least a ring? Does this object have a name?

What do you think?

Comment: These strings don't usually represent any kind of numbers in the natural interpretation that powers of two should still have a single $1$. To see some of the problems, what would be the square of
$$x=\ldots111.111\ldots=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}2^k?$$
You see the problem? What's the $2^0$ term of $x^2$? Assuming usual distributive laws $x^2$ would contain infinitely many terms of the form $2^k\cdot2^{-k}$, each contributing to the $2^0$ term.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Argumentatively $x = .... 111.111 ...$ is another representation of the number $0$ because $... 111 = -1$ and $.111... = 1$ so $x = -1 + 1 = 0$. No?

The thing is that it seems that you can soundly define addition and multiplication on those strings.

Comment: If you know complex analysis, the above problem is similar to a product of Laurent series of the form $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k z^k$. Without some complex analysis backing us up, it is impossible to multiply two such beasts for the same reason that there will be infinitely many $z^0$ terms (as well as others). Compare with the products of two such series where $k$ is constrained to a range like $[m,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,m]$. Two power series of the same type can be multiplied formally, but if you try to mix them, you need to deal with this problem one way or another.

Comment: Ah! Ok so while it seems "simple" to define addition, I understand that it might be tricky to define multiplication on those strings, is that what you imply? So we are at most left with a semi ring?

Comment: Continuing with your example, and $y=\ldots 0101.0101\ldots$. If carry is done in the usual way, we see that $y+y+y+y=y$. Or $y+y+y=x$. So may be also, $y=0$ or at least $3y=0$? Anyway, to talk about a ring you first need to specify A) its elements, and B) operations. If you want to equate certain strings, you want to describe equivalence classes of strings. What is the rule we can use to decide when two strings should be equated? What is the definition of the sum of two strings? The same with product?

Comment: We would first define an algorithm for addition/soustraction on those strings and the set of representations of the number $0$, $\bar{0}$.

Then two strings x, y are equated if $x - y \in \bar{0}$. 

I dont have either the algorithm or $\bar{0}$ precisely figured out though :D

Comment: As you pointed out it seems that a good starting point is to look at rationals that are both in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_2$ (they are exactly the rationals with odd denominator) and what happens when we concatenate the expressions in both worlds.

Comment: This looks oddly similar to the recent https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4280295/96384, and I raise the same objections as there, plus seconding what Jyrki writes here. There is (to my knowledge) no way to define a multiplication on such two-tailed strings which is at the same time natural and interesting. [Just one of these can always be done; after all, as a set such two-tailed sequences can be identified with any ring/field/whatever with cardinality of the continuum, of which there are too many to even know what to look for.]

Comment: Its crazy its the exact same question as the thread you pointed at! Thank you for this. What about the following multiplication definition: let's write $x = x_{\mathbb{Z}_2} + x_{[0,1]}$ same for $y$. Then $x*y = x_{\mathbb{Z}_2}*y_{\mathbb{Z}_2} + x_{[0,1]}*y_{[0,1]}$. Hmm that probably does not have the properties you'd want for multiplication though. And maybe the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is one of those sets to look for?

Comment: If you define the multiplicative structure as the one of the monoid product $\mathbb Z_2 \times [0,1]$, little insight seems attainable, *and* it looks unlikely that it would distribute over any additive structure proposed so far. As said, I think these questions are far too broad unless they impose severe restrictions on how addition / multiplication / whatever are supposed to behave. Otherwise, it sounds flippant but I can propose twelve different ways of turning such sequences into kind of a ring, and then ask the world if they are well-defined and if yes, what ring would come out.

Comment: Sure, the algebraic closure of some $\mathbb Q_p$ could be one of them. Or $M_{6}(\mathbb R \times \mathbb F_{17})$. Or $\mathbb C_{23} \times \mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$. Or certain subrings of the endomorphism ring of $(\mathbb Q(i\sqrt{5}) \times \mathbb Z_3)^{435}$. If we don't restrict how to define the addition and multiplication on our set, I can make it isomorphic to each of those.